# Network bound / network pipe monitoring on Linux?

Tags: linux, performance, monitoring, networking

I'm trying to analyze the performance of an application running on Linux.  I use a combination of vmstat/iostat/top to see if the machine is disk I/O bound or CPU bound, but I'm not sure what utility to use to monitor network usage.  Specifically, I'd like to know if the machine's network pipe is maxed out.  What utility should I use?

Answer (score 3):

I typically use the [iptraf](http://iptraf.seul.org/) utility for this purpose.  Many distributions have this packaged but do not install it by default.

Additionally, historical graphing such as that which is created by [Cacti](http://www.cacti.net/) is useful.

Comment: netstat can list bandwidth usage, errors, restarts etc. but can be cumbersome.

Answer (score 1):

Give a look at iftop.
If you want to monitor network performance, you can setup snmp and monitor snmp stats.
Or you could install ntop and have all the information you need

Comment: ntop's a good one.  It's part of my standard toolkit on firewalls and routers.

Comment: On routers/firewalls i'd install fprobe to export netflow statistics, instead of Ntop

Comment: Interesting.  What Open Source tool do you use as the collector?

Comment: Ntop on another server ;)

Comment: haha, nice.  Thanks.  That's a good idea, I think I'll implement that.