# How to monitor netword card saturation?

Tags: networking, bandwidth

What is a decent tool I can use on a ubuntu server command line to measure my network bandwidth on that machine to see if I'm saturating the network card or not? I have a crawler running on a box and I'm not sure how to best monitor if I need to add more boxes or not.

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Network bound / network pipe monitoring on Linux?](http://serverfault.com/questions/158553/network-bound-network-pipe-monitoring-on-linux)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Command line wise, [iptraf](http://iptraf.seul.org/) is one of my favorite tools for a quick login&check method, and should give you a quick idea of what your current speeds are as well as what the box is doing.

Its not command line, but for more long term monitoring, I would suggest SNMP monitoring. Cacti+snmp works very well to get constant information from your server, and creates up nice little graphs for you to see how your bandwidth is doing.